# removing java.endorsed.dirs from Tomcat on Eclipse with Java 9 and Java 10

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-9

I'm using Eclipse 4.7.3a with Tomcat 9.0.4 in the IDE. I upgraded from Java 8 to Java 10. I changed my `JAVA_HOME` to point to the JDK 10 installation. I went into Eclipse and created a new JDK installed JRE pointing at the Java 10 JDK, and selected it. I rebuilt my project, and tried to start the Tomcat server I had. It said:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\bin\tomcat\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
```

I poked around and found that in the Tomcat launch configuration in Eclipse, under the Arguments tab, there are the following VM arguments:

```
-Dcatalina.base="I:\work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1" -Dcatalina.home="C:\bin\tomcat" -Dwtp.deploy="I:\work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\bin\tomcat\endorsed"
```

I removed the last part, `-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\bin\tomcat\endorsed"`, and hit Apply, but the changes don't "stick"; when I come back to that dialog, the value is still there, and I still can't run Tomcat.

How can I removed the `java.endorsed.dirs` system property from the Eclipse Tomcat configuration?

Better yet, how can I avoid the problem altogether? Isn't Eclipse and Tomcat ready for Java 9+? Will a newer version of Tomcat 9 fix the problem? Should I remove and add back the Eclipse server? How can I get to the root of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have this [problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162) before and but after updating [WTP](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin to the latest version (3.9.5) which is not included even in the latest Eclipse (Oxygen.3a) to solve the problem.

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem. I recommend that answers include the full information in addition to the link. It would be a good idea to include the link to the WTP update site http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/oxygen/ for example. Cheers!

Comment: I found I also needed to be using the latest versions of JST in order for the changes to not be overridden by default.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was still occurring even in the latest Eclipse IDE 2019-12R with eclipse web tools platform release 3.16 running AdoptOpenJDK jdk-11.0.5.10-hotspot.

I did as the OP, found -Djava.endorsed.dirs in the Arguments tab under the VM arguments for Tomcat. Get there by right clicking your project, select Run As -> Run Configurations... then, search for tomcat. In my case I clicked on 'Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost', selected the Arguments tab and found the offending entry by scrolling down in the 'VM arguments' text box. I deleted the argument and it's referenced path. I restarted Eclipse and it seems to have stuck.