# JDK10 with Eclipse Oxygen giving Djava.endorsed error on Tomcat9 Start

Tags: java, eclipse

I have eclipse IDE oxygen latest version installed and downloaded the latest JDK 10 and setup it. 
I did installed latest WTP 3.4 with it and created a simple maven project.
The Tomcat is 9.0.10 and it is having issue when tried to start the server inside eclipse(oxygen). It gives below error:-

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=<path>\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules. Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I did confirmed that my oxygen and WTP are up to date and I dont want to roll back to Photon to make it work or degrade my JDK.

There are similar question on same error but either they are with old jdk(9) or landed up either making different suggestion (degrade jdk etc) or upgrading the eclipse, wtp etc resolved them. But mine is not answered and hence this question.

And yes, JDK10 appears to be supported with Tomcat9 as per table below:- 
[image]

Comment: Does Tomcat 9 support Java 10?  Did you read all the other questions about this same issue on StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes, it does says, JDK8 and later supported.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get help on the [Apache Tomcat mailing list](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Web Tools Platform (WTP) 3.9.5 on Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) on Windows 10, so I can use Tomcat 9 + Java 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50840727/2985643).

Comment: What do you mean by your comment _"I dont want to roll back to Photon"_? Photon was only released three weeks ago!

Comment: @skomisa, I meant that JDK10 support was introduced with oxygen3a, so there is no question to roll back(moved to ) to other version for any reason.

Comment: The Endorsed Standards Override mechanism was deprecated in JDK 8 and removed in JDK 9. It seems the Eclipse WTP project has an issue on this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162