# Launching Tomcat from Eclipse with OpenJDK10.0.2 does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to move to Java 10.0.2 (OpenJDK due to license).

I am using Eclipse Photon (and tried in Eclipse Oxygen)
Trying to use Tomcat v9.0.5
Running in Windows 7

All work fine with OpenJDK 1.8.0.171
But when I switch to OpenJDK 10.0.2 (or OpenJDK 9), I am told:-

*Java Virtual Machine Launcher

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.*

and then:-

*Problem Occurred

'Starting Tomcat v9.0 64bit' has encountered a problem.

Server Tomcat v9.0 64bit failed to start*

I can start it fine from the command line but not from within Eclipse.

I'm sure I must be missing something but cannot think what.

I've spent what seems like a long time looking for a solution but have found nothing.

Added in response to duffymo - Tomcat log says "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-9.0.5\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules."

Comment: Everything you are using is very "new". What happens if you use Java 9? Or, Oxygen?

Comment: Is there more detail in the Tomcat log?

Comment: Thanks, not tried OpenJDK 9, will try that now. I previously tried 10.0.1 and that had the same result.

Comment: Just tried OpenJDK 9 with Eclipse Oxygen, still not working (but works fine with OpenJDK 1.8.0.171)

Comment: Console log may be helpful. Thanks duffymo. It says "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-9.0.5\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules."

Comment: Did you check [this issue of tomcat 9 and java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085750/apache-tomcat-9-x-not-working-with-eclipse-java-10-0-1). In theory, Photon was supposed to resolve the issue, but the error message and description seem very similar to what the OP is reporting.

Comment: Also, I believe the specific bug report about the "-D" parameter [may be found here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162)

Comment: Seems like a bug in eclipse - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162 (sorry just later than KevinO)

Comment: See [_How to install Web Tools Platform (WTP) 3.9.5 on Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) on Windows 10, so I can use Tomcat 9 + Java 10?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50840727/2985643) although that relates to Photon only, and no solution is provided.

Comment: If you *upgraded* from Oxygen to Photon, you might need to retry with a fresh install of Photon.

Comment: Thanks. @nitind - The Photon is a fresh install (it always is for me, in case I need to continue using the Oxygen version - for occasions like this one). It's no big deal for me. I don't need Java 10 just was keen to use community build OpenJDK10 instead of Oracle build OpenJDK8.

Comment: How recent an OpenJDK build is it? Can you point me to the download?

Comment: 10.0.1 does not work (from here) @ntind - https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild (but 1.8 [same source] does work for me) 10.0.2 (from here http://jdk.java.net/10/ also does not work)